# How to tell whether a cell belong to a group row / item row in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, grouping, advanceddatagrid

I created a Advanced Data Grid and implemented a grouping using GroupingCollection2 on it.

I implemented a custom Item Renderer and when I start to scroll horizontally, the cells belong to the previous item is also displayed on the group row.

Please take a look at the screenshot.
[image]

How can I tell from my item renderer that this cell is belong to a group and should not be displayed?

Comment: What do you use for DataGrid source? Do you have it in ArrayCollection or in SQlite db ? Answer will depend on it :)